# When try to flutter run in iOS device, getting s6Runner11AppDelegateC11application

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am trying to run a Flutter app using command `flutter clean` and then `flutter run` on the iOS (iPhone 8) simulator for the first time. I'm getting the following error:

```
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39f0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ad79b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e39d4c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
        3   Runner                              0x0000000106f1d519 +[FIRApp appWasConfiguredTwice:usingOptions:] + 185
        4   Runner                              0x0000000106f1cf92 +[FIRApp configureWithName:options:] + 306
        5   Runner                              0x0000000106f1cd1f +[FIRApp configureWithOptions:] + 143
        6   Runner                              0x0000000106f1cc6d +[FIRApp configure] + 157
        7   Runner                              0x0000000106eb81a4 $s6Runner11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtF + 212
        8   Runner     <…>
This is taking longer than expected...
```

So I suspect the error is related to my "Firebase" dependency.

1) I have the podfile as follow:

```
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

2) I do see my `GoogleService-Info.plist` live under /ios/Runner.

3) My `AppDelegate.swfit` is as follow:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your log output starts with:

```
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
```

This comes from the flutter plugins which tries to init the Firebase app if it is not init yet.

The `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is called after that, so configuring the Firebase app in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method as stated in the iOS SDK documentation is not necessary when using the Flutter plugins.

So remove the changes in the `AppDelegate.swift` as follow:

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase // Remove this line

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    FirebaseApp.configure()  // Remove this line
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Because this is confusing, it may change in the future or be better documented, watch https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2466

Comment: But then... Firebase is not configured at all

Comment: Ok, I take that back, it still is... But how?

Comment: I found it. The flutter plugins seem to configure the Firebase instance themself. See for instance https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/28494710eea5287de1d62f51fc37541e5701289e/packages/firebase_remote_config/ios/Classes/FirebaseRemoteConfigPlugin.m#L33 . For some reasons, the safety check that checks if the instance is already configure doesn't work. See https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2466

Comment: Actually, that's because the init on the native side is called after the plugins init.
This is a correct answer, I have edited it to add more context